# How to assign the result of a random math problem to a var

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to do a command where the author gives the answer to a random math question and it answers with congrats or nopers, but for some reason the bot doesn't answer when the correct answer is given, I think it's a problem with the answer checking part but it can be other things too

```
client.on('message', async message => {
  
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("mb.start")) 
  {
    var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var simbolos = ["+", "*", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*3)];
    
    var pergunta = x + " " + simbolos + " " + y + "?"
    var respostacorreta = (eval(x + simbolos + y))
  
    message.channel.send(pergunta);
    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    const resposta = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {max: 999, time: 90000, errors: ['max', 'time']})
    
    if(resposta.content === (respostacorreta))
       {
         message.channel.send('you got the question right');
         console.log('Correct!')
       }
    else return messsage.reply('nopers');
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Ran your code through Prettier.
Added some comments with questions.
And what does the console log's i added output?

```
if (message.author.bot) return;

if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("mb.start")) {
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var simbolos = ["+", "*", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

  var pergunta = x + " " + simbolos + " " + y + "?";
  var respostacorreta = eval(x + simbolos + y);
  
  // Does this message get sent?
  message.channel.send(pergunta);

  const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
  
  const resposta = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
    max: 999,
    time: 90000,
    errors: ["max", "time"],
  });

  console.log(resposta)

  if (resposta.content === respostacorreta) {
    message.channel.send("you got the question right");
    console.log("Correct!");
  } else {
    // This looks like a typo, should be message?
    return messsage.reply("nopers");
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes the top message get sent, and yes it's a typo but just changing it didn't do anything thanks tho

Comment: The console log you added didn't output anything

Comment: Can you check if your filter function is correct. Try changing it to: `const filter = (m) => { console.log(m.author.id, message.author.id); return m.author.id === message.author.id; }` Just to see what it's comparing.

Comment: Also try changing the max value to 1.

Comment: Following your steps, the max value made the bot input work, but only the nopers, as from the const filter it output a huge log, and it seems like its not the problem.

Comment: It looks like awaitMessages tries to collect 999 messages from the author or waits 90000 before completing.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you await messages first thing? why is `const resposta = await message.channel.awaitMessages()` inside the "if"?

Split the problem into parts:

- make your bot always run `message.reply('nopers');`
- make your bot always run `message.channel.send('correct');`
- if both work, print content you got from the user and its type (number or String)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but worth a try.
There is probably a better method do do this, but I'm not that familiar with the discord api.

```
if (message.author.bot) return;

if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith("mb.start")) {
  const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  const y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  const simbolos = ["+", "*", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

  const pergunta = x + " " + simbolos + " " + y + "?";
  const respostacorreta = eval(x + simbolos + y);

  message.channel.send(pergunta);


  let gotCorrectAnswer = false;
  
  // Wait for one answer from the author
  // if it is correct stop loop, otherwise wait for next try
  while (!gotCorrectAnswer) {
    const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;
    const currentAnswer = await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
      max: 1,
      time: 60,
      error: ["max", "time"],
    });

    if (currentAnswer === respostacorreta) {
      message.channel.send("you got the question right");
      gotCorrectAnswer = true;
    } else {
      message.channel.send("Wrong! try again");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The bot spammed "Wrong! try again" using this code

Answer (score 0):

I redid the entire thing and the error turned out to be dumb instead of

```
if (resposta === respostacorreta)
```

It was meant to be

```
if (resposta == respostacorreta)
```

Sorry for wasting your times...